# MVC 3.0 : Create a URL for handler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

As we are using Url.Action() method to create a URL in MVC. Same method is not working for the Handler call. May I know reason behind it? What are the alternatives for it?

Comment: more info needed, exceptions stack etc ?

Comment: @krystanhonour . we are using Url.Action() method to create url in mvc. I used same method for create a url for handler but it is not working. May I know reason behind it? What are the alternatives for it?